# Useless static keyword in enclosed interface

Tags: java, java-14

If you take a look at `java.util.concurrent.Flow.Subscriber<T>` then you will notice that it is a static interface. However, this code works as well:

```
class MyCls {
  interface Enclosed {
  }
}

// somewhere ...
MyCls.Enclosed enclosed = // ...
```

As per my understanding, an interface can't be bound to an instance. Why is `Flow.Subscriber<T>` a static interface then?

Comment: @Andy My point is, it doesn't make sense. But I have noticed that this is repeated all over. *Why?* The question you marked as duplicate doesn't provide its detail.

Comment: Because whoever wrote the code put it there, either not knowing it's unnecessary or believing it's more readable (or some other reason); and there isn't any (or there is little) effort to change the JDK for things that don't make a semantic or substantial readability difference.

Comment: A nested interface is always static, whether the keyword is present or not. Though you seem more interested in why someone would type the keyword anyway. If that's the case, consider [edit]ing your question's title to something more like "_Why does Java's Flow.Subscriber interface use the 'static' keyword when it's unnecessary?_". If you do that then I think this question is clearly not a duplicate of the question linked by @Andy, but it may be opinion based.

Comment: It seems, the author of this particular code likes to be explicit. The `public` modifier on the methods within the interface is redundant too. Interestingly, the older interfaces of the same package, also written by Doug Lea, don’t have this style. Considering interfaces of this package only, his style changes between Java 7 and Java 8.

Comment: @Holger Interesting finding. I have been reading "concurrency in practice" by brain goetz and he seems to be doing this as well. For ex: `double d = (double) 10 / (double) 8;`. Now I think it's all about readability but tbh it creates more confusion ;)

Comment: @rockstar In the case of `double d = (double) 10 / (double) 8` there is actually a good reason for those casts (or at least the one on the denominator), `10 / 8` is 1, while `(double) 10 / (double) 8` is 1.25.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Totally agree but it can also be done `double d = (double) 10 / 8;` or `double d = 10 / (double) 8;`, that's the point.